# Unable to call controller method using get request in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Actually I am new to java spring mvc and currently stuck in a very simple problem.Basically I am deleting specific row of table but unable to call controller method `Remove`.

My `check.jsp` code of table

```
<table id="customers">
   <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Contact</th>
       <th>Edit</th>
       <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>
   <c:forEach items="${persons}" var="p">
        <tr>
             <td>${p.id}</td>
             <td>${p.name}</td>
             <td>${p.contact}</td>
             <td ><a href="#">edit</a></td>
             <td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${p.id}' />" >delete</a></td>
       </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

My `testController.java` code

```
@Controller
public class testController {
    @RequestMapping("/check")
    public ModelAndView getusers() 
    {
       ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("check");
       Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       session.beginTransaction();
       List list=session.createQuery("from Person").list();
       mv.addObject("persons",list);
       session.getTransaction().commit();   
       mv.addObject("message","Welcome");
       return mv;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id)
    {
       //System.out.println("It IS RUNNING");
       ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("check");
       Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       session.beginTransaction();

       Person P;
       P = (Person)session.load(Person.class,id);   
       session.delete(P);
       session.flush();

       session.getTransaction().commit(); 

       return mv; 
    }
}
```

This is the whole class code of `testController` in which `getusers()` method is working perfectly fine while `removePerson()` is not working thus giving `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found` error

Comment: As i mentioned I am newbie in this framework so If I do have some basic mistakes Plz point out them instead of down voting Thankx

Comment: I think the reason of the downvotes may be the lack of elements to help answering the question. Are you getting any error messages? Did you inspect the generated HTML in order to verify if the link to your endpoint was correctly created?

Comment: I am getting this error `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found`  when i try to click on delete button

Comment: In this case maybe the endpoint is not correct. Does the class that contains the `Remove` method is annotated with `@Controller`? Is it also annotated with `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: Yeah this class also have `getusers()` method which is perfectly working fine.

Comment: @GustavoPassini i posted the whole class code

Comment: try changing `RequestMethod.GET` to `RequestMethod.POST`

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul No luck I did it.

Comment: I just noticed that in your `td` it says `/remove/${p.id}` but the name of your method is `removePerson`

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul but i think `@RequestMapping` maps the request to the corresponding method not the method name

Answer (score 0):

After wasting 1 day I finally figured out there is no problem in my controller class, the main problem lies in my `dispatcher-servlet.xml` mappings in which i changed my `<prop key="check.htm">test</prop>` to `<prop key="/check/**">test</prop>` and boom the `removePerson()` method is working perfectly fine.